# Convergence not completed in scf for bands

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I want to calculate scf for bands calculation. Before I can proceed, I face an error of convergence:

```
End of self-consistent calculation

convergence NOT achieved after  80 iterations: stopping
```

Kindly,help me fix this.

Comment: It is not that we don't want to help you, but with this little information, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: @RomanPunk previously you asked a question where your calculation wouldn't even start. Now your calculation stops because maximum allowed iterations are finished. Does that mean you figured out the answer of your last question and you do not need answer for that anymore?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you set `electron_maxstep = 80` in the `&ELECTRONS` namelits of your scf input file. The default value is `electron_maxstep = 100`. This keyword denotes the maximum number of iterations in a single scf cycle. You can know more about this [here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm803).

In order to fix this, you can use one of the following two strategies. Firstly, increase the parameter to `electron_maxstep = 100`, `electron_maxstep = 200` or even more. But please make sure that your energy is actually converging. Increasing the number of `electron_maxstep` will only help if the energy is converging slowly. Otherwise if the accuracy is alternating rapidly, or it converges upto a certain value and diverges again, then this might not help at all. That would indicate that either you have some problematic system or your input file is problematic.

To check how the accuracy changes, you can use the following command:

```
grep -s 'estimated scf accuracy' scf.out
```

The second strategy is to lower the convergence thresholds. Maybe you set the convergence threshold too tight. The default convergence threshold of `conv_thr = 1.D-6` is good enough for most purposes. Also, in case in your scf calculation, you set `tstress` or `tprnfor` to `.TRUE.`, then other convergence thresholds such as `etot_conv_thr` and `forc_conv_thr` will also play role. Without the input file there is nothing else to say. That's why sharing your input file when asking a question is a good idea so that people who wants to help can actually help you.

Comment: thanks a lot sir